# convert string to html in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I am wondering if there is an easy way to convert a string to HTML as when I am trying to convert a string having valid html, to HTML, href links and line breaks. I am using `DOMParser().parseFromString` method stated on `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser`

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    "....snip..... <br><br> If you do not have an account, please register here.<a href= https://redmine.ixsystems.com/account/register </a>", 'text/html'
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in Angular, do it the Angular way :

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<p>Your HTML</p>');
}
```